# RecyclerView Adapter notify data changed

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

There is my activity:

```
public class EventDetailsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Event event;
private ArrayList<User> subscribedUsers;
private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
private String eventId;
private SubscribedUsersAdapter adapter;
private Context context;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_event_details);
    context = this;
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    eventId = extras.getString("eventId");
    setUpEvent();
}

private void setUpEvent() {
    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    final DatabaseReference mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("events").child(eventId);
    mDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            String eventType = dataSnapshot.child("eventType").getValue().toString();
            String description = dataSnapshot.child("description").getValue().toString();
            Object object = dataSnapshot.child("startingDate").getValue();
            HashMap result = (HashMap) object;
            int year = Integer.parseInt(result.get("year").toString());
            int month = Integer.parseInt(result.get("month").toString());
            int day = Integer.parseInt(result.get("date").toString());
            int hour = Integer.parseInt(result.get("hours").toString());
            int minute = Integer.parseInt(result.get("minutes").toString());
            Date startingDate = new Date(year,month,day,hour,minute,0);
            object = dataSnapshot.child("location").getValue();
            result = (HashMap) object;
            double latitude = Double.parseDouble(result.get("latitude").toString());
            double longitude = Double.parseDouble(result.get("longitude").toString());
            LatLng location = new LatLng(latitude,longitude);
            String userId = dataSnapshot.child("userId").getValue().toString();
            String userName = dataSnapshot.child("userName").getValue().toString();
            String userPicture = dataSnapshot.child("userPicture").getValue().toString();
            subscribedUsers = new ArrayList<User>();
            if (dataSnapshot.hasChild("subscribedUsers")) {
                mDatabase.child("subscribedUsers").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        for (DataSnapshot childSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                            String userId = childSnapshot.child("userId").getValue().toString();
                            String name = childSnapshot.child("name").getValue().toString();
                            String picture = childSnapshot.child("picture").getValue().toString();
                            User subscribedUser = new User(userId, name, picture);
                            if (containsUser(subscribedUsers, subscribedUser) == -1) {
                                subscribedUsers.add(subscribedUser);
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });

            }
            event = new Event(eventId, eventType,description,startingDate,location,userId, userName, userPicture);
            setText();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}

private void setText()
{
    ImageView mProfilePicture = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.profilePicture);
    if (!EventDetailsActivity.this.isFinishing()) {
        Glide
                .with(this)
                .load(event.getUserPicture())
                .into(mProfilePicture);
    }
    TextView mUserName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.userName);
    mUserName.setText(event.getUserName());
    TextView mEventType = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.eventType);
    mEventType.setText(event.getEventType());
    TextView mDescription = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.description);
    mDescription.setText(event.getDescription());
    if (!EventDetailsActivity.this.isFinishing()) {
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.mapView);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback()
        {
            @Override
            public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
                googleMap.clear();
                googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(event.getLocation()));
                googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(event.getLocation(),12.0f));
            }
        });
    }
    TextView mStartingDate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.startingDate);
    Date startingDate = event.getStartingDate();
    String displayText = String.valueOf(startingDate.getYear());
    int month = startingDate.getMonth() + 1;
    if (month/10 == 0)
    {
        displayText = displayText + ".0" + month;
    }
    else
    {
        displayText = displayText + "." + month;
    }
    if (startingDate.getDate()/10 == 0)
    {
        displayText = displayText + ".0" + startingDate.getDate();
    }
    else
    {
        displayText = displayText + "." + startingDate.getDate();
    }
    if (startingDate.getHours()/10 == 0)
    {
        displayText = displayText + ". 0" + startingDate.getHours();
    }
    else
    {
        displayText = displayText + ". " + startingDate.getHours();
    }
    if (startingDate.getMinutes()/10 == 0)
    {
        displayText = displayText + ":0" + startingDate.getMinutes();
    }
    else
    {
        displayText = displayText + ":" + startingDate.getMinutes();
    }
    mStartingDate.setText(displayText);
    setUpRecyclerView();
    subscribe();
}

private void setUpRecyclerView() {
    adapter = new SubscribedUsersAdapter(this,subscribedUsers);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
}

private void subscribe()
{
    FirebaseAuth mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    if (mAuth.getCurrentUser() != null) {
        final String userId = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
        DatabaseReference mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users").child(userId);
        mDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                String userName = dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue().toString();
                String userPicture = dataSnapshot.child("picture").getValue().toString();
                User user = new User(userId, userName, userPicture);
                userSubscribe(user);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
    else
    {
        userSubscribe(null);
    }
}

private void userSubscribe(final User user) {
    Button mSubscribeButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.subscribeButton);
    if (user == null)
    {
        mSubscribeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(EventDetailsActivity.this, getResources().getString(R.string.logInToSubscribe), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Intent loginIntent = new Intent(EventDetailsActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
                loginIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(loginIntent);
            }
        });
    }
    else if (containsUser(subscribedUsers,user) == -1)
    {
        mSubscribeButton.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.subscribe));
        mSubscribeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                DatabaseReference mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("events").child(event.getEventId());
                subscribedUsers.add(user);
                mDatabase.child("subscribedUsers").setValue(subscribedUsers);
            }
        });
    }
    else
    {
        mSubscribeButton.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.unsubscribe));
        mSubscribeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                DatabaseReference mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("events").child(event.getEventId());
                int position = containsUser(subscribedUsers,user);
                subscribedUsers.remove(position);
                mDatabase.child("subscribedUsers").removeValue();
                mDatabase.child("subscribedUsers").setValue(subscribedUsers);
            }
        });
    }
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    this.finish();
}

private int containsUser(ArrayList<User> users, User user)
{
    for (int i=0; i<users.size(); ++i)
    {
        if (users.get(i).getUserId().equals(user.getUserId()))
        {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
}
```

And my adapter:

```
public class SubscribedUsersAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SubscribedUsersAdapter.ViewHolder>{

private Context context;
private ArrayList<User> items;

public SubscribedUsersAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<User> items) {
    this.context = context;
    this.items = items;
}

protected static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public ImageView mProfilePictureView;
    public TextView mUserName;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        mProfilePictureView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.profilePictureView);
        mUserName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.userName);
    }
}

@Override
public SubscribedUsersAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.single_user, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(v);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    final User item = items.get(position);
    Glide
            .with(context)
            .load(item.getPicture())
            .into(holder.mProfilePictureView);
    holder.mUserName.setText(item.getName());
    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent profileIntent = new Intent(context, ProfileActivity.class);
            profileIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            profileIntent.putExtra("userId", item.getUserId());
            context.startActivity(profileIntent);
        }
        });
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return items.size();
}
}
```

When the activity starts firstly, the data is displayed well in RecyclerView, but if a user subscribes to the event or unsubscribe from it, the RecyclerView will be empty.
I tried with notifyDataSetChanged, notifyItemRangeInserted, notifyItemRangeRemoved, but none of them worked or I didn't use it well. I don't know.
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for (DataSnapshot childSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        String userId = childSnapshot.child("userId").getValue().toString();
                        String name = childSnapshot.child("name").getValue().toString();
                        String picture = childSnapshot.child("picture").getValue().toString();
                        User subscribedUser = new User(userId, name, picture);
                        if (containsUser(subscribedUsers, subscribedUser) == -1) {
                            subscribedUsers.add(subscribedUser);
                        }
                    }
```

after that just add this line

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: Wow! Thanks! Lots of things I tried yesterday, but everything in mSubscribeButton.setOnClickListener I did. I did not even think it should be here.